# How can I change menu bar colour in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, windows-10-universal

[Eclipse Dark Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1gOh.jpg)

I am using the dark theme, as seen from the picture above, but I can't change the colour of the menu bar and title bar. They are annoying me. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your OS? Win 8/10 from the looks of the screenshot? I am afraid that this is an OS configuration thing that cannot be changed from Eclipse itself, you should change the os window config/theme to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the OS is win 10. I was afraid it might be a Windows thing. I suppose there is not a way to change it so that it only affects Eclipse's menu bar :(

Comment: Sadly no :(. If you found my answer useful please remember to "tick" it as correct or mark it as useful (or even both! :P).

Comment: I cannot find a setting or the menu bar colour in Windows 10. The menu bar (not the title bar) is made by the window toolkit. Which toolkit does eclipse use?